# comm command not comparing words

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, comm

I am trying to learn shell programming and for that I am using ubuntu app in windows 10, I read about the comm command and as I have understood it it should be working as below

```
file1.txt    file2.txt
abc          abc
cde          efg
a            b
b            c

the result should be
a
cde
             abc
             b
      c
      efg

but what I am getting is

abc
a
cde            
              b
       efg
       abc
       c
```

this is how I used the command

```
comm file1.txt file2.txt
```

I suspect its because I am using it on a windows app but other commands such as grep uniq ps pwd ... all are working fine
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows is not the problem here. You used `comm` in the wrong way. `man comm` states

> comm - compare two **sorted** files line by line

Therefore, you have to sort both files first.

Use

```
sort file1.txt > file1sorted
sort file2.txt > file2sorted
comm file1sorted file2sorted
```

Or if you are using `bash` (not plain `sh` or some other shell)

```
comm <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```